# Android Fragment transaction - replacing fragment leaves the old one with strange state

Tags: android, fragment, orientation-changes

I have strange behaviour. Every time i replace the same type of fragment in Activity (using transaction), the new Fragment instance is added to Fragment List. The old instances remains active in Fragment Manager and after orientation change are visible on the screen (although not clickable).

My Activity Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

-->

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cubesoft.zenfolio.moments.app.activity.MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.cubesoft.zenfolio.moments.app.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentConnectionStatus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.cubesoft.zenfolio.fragment.ConnectionStatusFragment" />
```

My code that changes fragments:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    mCurrentDrawerPosition = position;
    // update the main content by replacing fragments


    List<Fragment> fragmemts = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();

    switch (position) {
    case 0:{
        if ( getMyApplication().getGroupModel().getUsersCount() > 0  ) {
            final Fragment fragment = UserSelectionFragment.newInstance();

            final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            //fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            final FragmentTransaction tr = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();

            tr.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            tr.addToBackStack(null);
            tr.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
            tr.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            tr.commit();

        } else {
            final Fragment fragment = MomentsFragment.newInstance(mUsername);

            final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            //fragmentManager.popBackStack();

            final FragmentTransaction tr = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            tr.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            //tr.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
            tr.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            tr.addToBackStack(null);

            tr.commit();
        }





        break;
    }

    case 1: {
        final Fragment fragment = DownloadFragment.newInstance();
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        //fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        final FragmentTransaction tr = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        tr.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        tr.addToBackStack(null);

        tr.commit();
        break;
    }

    /*case 2:
        fragment = UserSelectionFragment.newInstance();
        break;*/

    }


}
```

---

The UserSelectionFragment is displayed incorrectly after several orientation changes, old instances of UserSelectionFragment remains in Fragment List but their View objects are null.

What is wrong?

Comment: did you figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

```
 tr.addToBackStack(null);
```

To me this adds your frgament to the backstack and thats the reason why they are kept in your fragment list. Their view are null because they have been destroyed before going to backgroud.